# How to modify content inside <h1> tag only using HTML page not using JavaScript

Tags: html

I want the text "Hello from this side" to change if the CSS media query matches.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello from this side</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

In other words, how do I change the content in `<h1>` tag, whenever the page runs in a browser without using JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I want whenever this page is run on browser inside <h1> tag i want add some text (not permanently) that's it. Is it possible without using JS?

Comment: You can do this with `@media` css

Comment: @Adhitya can you please tell me how?

Comment: Say more about what you need or how this is useful.

Comment: Do you want the text two say something different to a user on a device with a small screen or if the width is less than say 640 pixels, for example?

Answer (score 1):

This example added text with `@media` css, setting up `max-width` or `min-width`.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="example-h1"></h1> 
</body>
<html>
```

**@media CSS**

```
#example-h1:before {
    content: "This is some great text here.";
}

@media (max-width: 670px) {
  #example-h1:before {
     content: "This is some other super great text.";
  }
}
```

**Will get output like this snippet**

```css
#example-h1:before {
    content: "Yes I'm here";
}

@media (max-width: 670px) {
  #example-h1:before {
     content: "Oh no! I'm There.";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="example-h1"></h1> 
</body>
<html>
```